# from any people vs from any two people

Tags: comparison

Would you be so kind to help explain the difference between:

no play ever gets the same reaction from any two audiences.

and

no play ever gets the same reaction from any audience.

I could understand the difference if they are used in other contexts, say, "I don't like any animal" and "I don't like any two animals."; or, "every animal is cute." and "every two animals are cute."

However, in the comparison at the beginning, I feel two sentences mean the same. Would you please explain whether they are different, or they are the same?

Answer (score 1):

*No play ever gets the same reaction from any two audiences.* is a way of saying that *every* audience reacts differently.

*...the same reaction from any audience* prompts the question "The same as what?". *Same* requires two things to be compared.

With respect, your sentences *I don't like any two animals* and *every two animals are cute* do not make sense. Why would you dislike two random animals?

Comment: Thank you for the comment, Kate Bunting! Replying to your first question, I took "any audience" as the objects being compared. Thus, I read the second example sentence as a comparison between each audience; the second sentence becomes "a play always gets a different reaction from an audience to another audience." Is my reading correct?

Comment: The second sentence would be more naturally expressed as "No play gets the same reaction from _every_ audience".